# How to load 16-bit images into Metal textures?

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, metal

The recommended method of using `MTKTextureLoader.newTexture` doesn't work with 16-bit images.

1. The `named:` version silently converts the image to 8-bit pixel format
2. The `cgImage:` version terminates with `Image decoding failed`

Both UIImage and NSImage supports loading 16-bit images, and have their handy `.cgimage` method which converts to CGImage in a one liner so getting a CGImage on both platforms is solved.

How can I write a function which converts a CGImage and returns a 16-bit Metal texture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `loadEXRTexture` function below loads an extended-range image and converts its pixels to half-precision floating-point, storing the resulting pixel data into an `MTLTexture` with the `.rgba16Float` format. It attempts to preserve the original range of the floating-point image by using `CGImageSource` options that alter its behavior from the Quartz default (which applies a "decode" function that compresses the source data into a range suitable for drawing into a bitmap context). It assumes that the image created by the image source has three floating-point components packed in RGB order.

```
func convertRGBF32ToRGBAF16(_ src: UnsafePointer<Float>, _ dst: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>, pixelCount: Int) {
    for i in 0..<pixelCount {
        storeAsF16(src[i * 3 + 0], dst + (i * 4) + 0)
        storeAsF16(src[i * 3 + 1], dst + (i * 4) + 1)
        storeAsF16(src[i * 3 + 2], dst + (i * 4) + 2)
        storeAsF16(1.0, dst + (i * 4) + 3)
    }
}

func loadEXRTexture(_ url: URL, device: MTLDevice) -> MTLTexture? {
    guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil) else { return nil }

    let options = [ kCGImageSourceShouldCache : true, kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat : true ] as CFDictionary
    guard let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options) else { return nil }

    let descriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: .rgba16Float,
                                                              width: image.width,
                                                              height: image.height,
                                                              mipmapped: false)
    descriptor.usage = .shaderRead
    guard let texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: descriptor) else { return nil }

    if image.bitsPerComponent == 32 && image.bitsPerPixel == 96 {
        let srcData: CFData! = image.dataProvider?.data
        CFDataGetBytePtr(srcData).withMemoryRebound(to: Float.self, capacity: image.width * image.height * 3) { srcPixels in
            let dstPixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>.allocate(capacity: 4 * image.width * image.height)
            convertRGBF32ToRGBAF16(srcPixels, dstPixels, pixelCount: image.width * image.height)
            texture.replace(region: MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, image.width, image.height),
                            mipmapLevel: 0,
                            withBytes: dstPixels,
                            bytesPerRow: MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size * 4 * image.width)
            dstPixels.deallocate()
        }
    }

    return texture
}
```

You'll need to include this utility in a bridging header since, to the best of my knowledge, Swift doesn't have the `__fp16` type or any equivalent:

```
#include <stdint.h>
static inline void storeAsF16(float value, uint16_t *pointer) { *(__fp16 *)pointer = value; }
```

Comment: Getting the CGImage is just a one liner both for NSImage and UIImage with `.cgimage` so that's good. What isn't clear is how to convert CGImage data to MTLTexture. I've updated my question.

Comment: What color space does the image have? I'm concerned that you might be getting an image that has already had its components compressed (which is what Quartz does [by default](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/kcgimagesourceshouldallowfloat?language=objc)). Does the color space have `bpc = 16` and `kCGImageByteOrder16Little`; `bpc = 32` and `kCGImageByteOrder32Little | kCGBitmapFloatComponents`; or some other combination?

Comment: Rewrote my answer in response to the actual question.

Comment: Wow, you actually did the Float version for EXR, which I've given up on, but it is so valuable! I was just thinking of simple 16-bit PNG images which are UInt16. For UInt16 I figured out how to do it based actually on your code: https://github.com/warrenm/slug-swift-metal/blob/master/SwiftMetalDemo/MBEDemoThree.swift#L23

But I could't make it work with Float, as it was giving me crazy small values, like -e17, etc. I'll be checking your version.